# flutter web error when try to build and existing flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have an existing flutter app and try to run it on web but when I try to run 
it shows a blank page and I saw an error on chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
   at remote_module.dart:15
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your full code, It looks like your trying to extend a class in the file remote_web.dart. It may be from a package, I can tell you a lot of packages don't work on Flutter Web, which otherwise would work on iOS/Android.

Best bet would to look through your code to find what Class is having the issue. Otherwise open a new question with your full code.

Comment: it's already a class in my code on my code 
and this the class 
```class UserRemoteModule extends Module {
  @override
  void configure(GetIt get) => get
    ..registerSingleton<UserRemoteDataSource>(
        UserRemoteDataSourceImp(UserProfileMapperRemote(), get<UserTypeProvider>()))
    ..registerSingleton<RemoteSMSDataSource>(RemoteSMSDataSourceImp());
}
```